# How can I ensure that an iterator method will not yield any null items?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I'm wondering whether it is possible to ensure (using [code-contracts](/questions/tagged/code-contracts)) that an iterator method will never yield a null item.

This simplified method:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> CreateSomeObjects()
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<object>>() != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.ForAll(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<object>>(), _ => _ != null));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        yield return new object();
    }
}
```

Results in a compile time warning similar to this:

> CodeContracts: MyClass.CreateSomeObjects()[0x9]: ensures unproven: Contract.ForAll(Contract.Result>(), _ => _ != null)

What can I do to prove it to the static checker?

Comment: I was trying to get this same thing working, but for me it didn't even give any compile time warning. After a lot of searching I ended up using a different solution without code contracts, because I simply could not find a solution with them. I would try using legacy code to check if it's not null inside a Code Contract block and close it with `Contract.EndContractBlock()`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.endcontractblock(v=vs.110).aspx. Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way you can put contracts on iterators is:

```
public class Graph
{
    public IEnumerable<Node> Nodes(Graph g)
    {
        Contract.Requires(g != null);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.ForAll(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<Nodei>>, node => node != null));
        foreach (var x in g.MethodForGettingNodes())
        yield return x;
    }
}
```

The contracts above make sure that callers don’t pass in a null parameter, and the method itself guarantees
that all elements in the resulting collection are non-null.

**Currently, the static checker does not reason about collections and thus will not be able to prove the
postcondition above.**

According to documentation they still do not fix it since 2009, I had problems with cc 2 years ago, and they still did not fix it and i think they wont.

Comment: Thanks. For clarity the docs (http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/2/7/C2715F76-F56C-4D37-9231-EF8076B7EC13/userdoc.pdf) says in section 6.6.1:  when writing iterators using the C# yield support the static contract checker will not
be able to prove postconditions.

Comment: I wonder, what would happen if you put `Contract.Assert(x != null)` inside the `foreach` loop, right before the `yield return x`?